# Getting from Split, Croatia to Venice, Italy

Tags: croatia

In July, my girlfriend and I are traveling to Croatia, and then need to travel from Split to meet up with my family near Venice.

I've tried to look for train routes online but haven't found anything that could be done within a day, as the routes I've seen take us quite out of the way. We're looking at a car rental but the cost to drop off that far away is pretty prohibitive.

Are there any services or places to search for them? We're open to all types of travel, as long as the overall trip wouldn't take longer than a day.

Comment: Search rome2rio.com, I have taken bus from split to Venice which is around 12 to 15 hours.

Comment: [Rome2rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Split/Venice) also shows EasyJet and Volotea fly this route fairly inexpensively.

Comment: According to [The Man in Seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/venice-to-ljubljana-and-zagreb-by-train.htm), "Sadly, there are now no mainline express trains at all across the border linking Venice with Ljubljana & Zagreb."  He notes, though, that there is planned to be cross-border service starting in September 2018 — too late for you, but maybe useful for future folks in your situation.  (As a substitute, he recommends an Zagreb–Venice itinerary that starts at 0650, which probably wouldn't be possible if you have to travel Split–Zagreb first.)

Comment: I suppose you could take the overnight train from Split–Zagreb.  It'd probably be just under 24 hours door to door, but I don't know if that counts as "longer than a day".

Comment: @MichaelSeifert We are actually planning on potentially (50%) visiting Plitvice, so going through Zagreb *may* be an option

Answer (score 5):

I traveled in Croatia last fall, and like you wanted to get from the Dalmatian coast to Italy.

We ended up flying, but another option is taking the [ferry](https://www.jadrolinija.hr/en/schedule/LineSearchResults/Index/2331792/2331731/08062018) which runs from Split to Ancona, Italy a few times a week. The ferry runs overnight, so you can spend your sleeping time traveling.

Comment: This sounds great! Thank you. We were aware of a ferry from a less convenient city, I'll look into this option.